# force behat to use in memory db with laravel 4.2 during curl requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, behat

I'm trying to get some Behavior tests integrated into my API test suite.  I'm leveraging Laravel 4.2 and already have a nice suite of unit tests.  The problem I'm running into is persistent data after these tests suite run - as well as correctly populated seed data.

I've tried to link sqlite into my bootstrap process following a [few examples](https://gist.github.com/davidstanley01/9405314) I've seen in various places online, but all this is really doing is setting up my DB when I call behat from CLI - during the application run (most specifically any curl requests out to the API) laravel still ties my DB to my local configuration which uses a mysql db.

here's an example snippet of a test suite,  the `Adding a new track` scenario is one where I'd like to have my API use the sqlite when the request and payload is made to my API.

```
Feature: Tracks

    Scenario: Finding all the tracks
        When I request "GET /api/v1/tracks"
        Then I get a "200" response

    Scenario: Finding an invalid track
        When I request "GET /api/v1/tracks/1"
        Then I get a "404" response

    Scenario: Adding a new track
        Given I have the payload:
             """
             {"title": "behat add", "description": "add description", "short_description": "add short description"}
             """                             
         When I request "POST /api/v1/tracks"
         Then I get a "201" response
```

Here is a snippet of my bootstrap/start.php file.  What I'm I am trying to accomplish is for my behat scenario (ie: Adding a new track) request to hit the testing config so I can manage w/ a sqlite db.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('*.local'),
    'production' => array('api'),
    'staging' => array('api-staging'),
    'virtualmachine' => array('api-vm'),
    'testing' => array('*.testing'),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Laraval does not know about Behat. Create a special environment for it, with its own database.

Here is what I have in my start.php:

```
if (getenv('APP_ENV') && getenv('APP_ENV') != '') 
{
    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
    {
            return getenv('APP_ENV');
    });
} 
else 
{
    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

            'local' => array('*.local', 'homestead'),
            /* ... */
    ));
}
```

APP_ENV is set in your Apache/Nginx VirtualHost config. For apache:

```
SetEnv APP_ENV acceptance
```

Create a special local test URL for Behat to use and put that in the VirtualHost entry.

I recommend using an SQLite file-based database. Delete the file before each Feature or Scenario. Found it to be much quicker than MySQL. I want to use the SQLite in-memory mode but I could not find a way to persist data between requests with the in-memory database.